# Want to move my object vertically and horizontal, my code move in angles

Tags: java

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Game extends JPanel {

    Ball ball = new Ball(this);
    Number123 num123 = new Number123(this);

    public Game(){
        addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            @Override
            public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            }

            @Override
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                ball.keyReleased(e);
            }

            @Override
            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                ball.keyPressed(e);
            }
        });
        setFocusable(true);
    }

    private void move() {
        ball.move();

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        ball.paint(g2d);
        num123.paintComponent(g2d);
}

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Two sprites");
        Game game = new Game();
        frame.add(game);
        frame.setSize(600, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        while (true) {
            game.move();
            game.repaint();
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
}




}
```

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

public class Ball implements ActionListener, KeyListener{

    int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int xa = 0;
    int ya = 0;
    private Game game;

    public Ball(Game game){
        this.game= game;
    }

     void move(){
         if (x + xa > 0 && x + xa < game.getWidth()-60)
                x = x + xa;
         if (y + ya > 0 && y + ya < game.getHeight()-60)
            y = y + ya;
    }
    public void paint(Graphics2D g){
        g.fillOval(x, y, 30, 30);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        if  (xa  == 1){
            xa = 1;}
         if (xa == -1){
                xa = -1;
        }
         if  (ya  == 1){
                ya = 1;}
             if (ya == -1){
                    ya = -1;
            }

    }



    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT)
            xa = -1;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT)
            xa = 1;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
            ya = -1;
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        ya = 1;
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

new to java so sorry if its a simple answer.

when i run program my circle object moves in angles not vertically and horizontal.

Comment: Not sure what you wanted to do in` keyReleased()`, but it actually does nothing.

Comment: trying set up snake like game where when pushed right it continues right until direction change

Comment: Please edit question an add that context explanation you give in comment INSIDE the question.

Comment: I would recommend debugging what you think the values should be.  My guess would be that you never set `xa` or `ya` back to zero, so everything always moves at a 45 degree angle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `xa` to 0 when you want to move vertically, and `ya` to 0 when you want to move horizontally.  They get initialized that way, but never get reset.

Comment: thank you,  next step keep it moving until next direction is pressed.